# How to model discontinuities in a NonlinearStateSpaceModel

Tags: control-systems, nonlinear

I know that it is possible to model discontinuities like bouncing and other collisions by using WhenEvent with NDSolve.

However, I am using the tools for Non linear systems and I'd like to know if it's possible to model collisions in a similar way when using OutputResponse with a system model. I tried using WhenEvent but it didn't work.